# Protobuf generated classes cannot be found when using gradle

Tags: java, gradle, protocol-buffers, grpc

If I follow the instruction in the [grpc-java](https://github.com/grpc/grpc-java) readme and I use maven, the protobuf generated files appear in the `target` directory and are subsequently in the classpath for me to extend etc. However, when I use gradle, the generated classes appear in the `build` directory and are absent from the classpath. I'm fairly new to gradle so I'm not really sure why it's behaving so differently.

**My build.gradle file**

```
apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'com.google.protobuf'

buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.google.protobuf:protobuf-gradle-plugin:0.8.5'
    }
}

group 'co.example'
version '1.0-SNAPSHOT'

sourceCompatibility = 1.8

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    compile 'io.grpc:grpc-netty-shaded:1.15.1'
    compile 'io.grpc:grpc-protobuf:1.15.1'
    compile 'io.grpc:grpc-stub:1.15.1'
    testCompile group: 'junit', name: 'junit', version: '4.12'
}

protobuf {
    protoc {
        artifact = "com.google.protobuf:protoc:3.5.1-1"
    }
    //noinspection GroovyAssignabilityCheck
    plugins {
        grpc {
            artifact = 'io.grpc:protoc-gen-grpc-java:1.15.1'
        }
    }
    generateProtoTasks {
        all()*.plugins {
            grpc {}
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

It looks like for gradle (if you want to use the generated stubs/server interfaces) in the project where your `proto` files live in (i.e. the project is not just for generating jars and publishing them) then you'll need to add `generatedFilesBaseDir` to your `build.gradle` file:

```
protobuf {
    generatedFilesBaseDir = "$projectDir/src/main/java/generated"
    ...
}
```

Once you've done this, the stubs should be in your classpath.

```
public class SomeServer extends MyProtoClassGrpc.PDFExtractImplBase {}
```